# how can I display QProgressBar like this？

Tags: c++, qt

how to add my own pic to QProgressBar to make it look  more beautiful（not only change color）；thanks！I want add pic like other controls（QPushButton，Lable....）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**QProgressBar**'s border, chunk, and text-align can be customized using style sheets.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qprogressbar)

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you reply for your time!can you show me an example!I try every stylesheet but the progress bar's clor not change,the selection-background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0.0490196 rgba(0, 170, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(73, 96, 255, 255));will let the bar become black!Not I want color!

Comment: oh!I'm sorry I find the example,I'm new user!Please forgive me!